# Unable to display value from one intent to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I Want to display values according to my checkbox status..

The Code I Have Used Is..

```
if((cb1).isChecked()==true){
        str="abc";
    }



    public void chk_med(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Medicine.this, chk_med.class);
    Medicine.this.startActivity(intent);
    intent.putExtra("fvr", str);
```

Code For chk_med

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.disp_med);
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    String Value1;
    Value1 = extras.getString("fvr");



    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_res);
    t1.setText(Value1);

}
```

what seems to be the error?
Plz help guyz.

I Changed the code to

```
public void chk_med(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Medicine.this, chk_med.class);
    intent.putExtra("fvr", a);
    Medicine.this.startActivity(intent);
```

but still it displays nothing in chk_med intent

Comment: try keeping putExtra before startActivity....

Comment: This Thing Worked But Now It Shows Nothing In New Intent i.e chk_med

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving the `extra` to the Intent **after** starting the new Activity. Therfore, once you launch that new Activity, you never actually get the extra you wanted.

This means you should change your code so it is:

```
 public void chk_med(View view){
    if(cb1.isChecked())
       str="abc";
    else
       str = "xyz";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Medicine.this, chk_med.class);
    intent.putExtra("fvr", str);
    Medicine.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

This allows the extra to be given to the Intent at the right time.

Also consider proper Java naming conventions: Classes start with capitals, and variables *don't* (camelcase).

Comment: @A-C This Thing Worked But Now It Shows Nothing In New Intent i.e chk_med

Comment: For cleaner code, you should do `String Value1 = getIntent().getStringExtra ("fvr");` in your new Activity. Also check in the `chk_med()` method that `str` has a valid value.

Comment: @Vikram Singh
@nathan

can you let me know how can I Display Valye according to selected checkbox

I Used 
      `if((cb1).isChecked()==true){
          str="abc";
      }`

but still it does not seems to work

Comment: @HarshShah what exactly doesn't work with that? Is cb1 a [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html)? I updated my code so that you should **definitely** get a value in your next Activity.

Comment: @HarshShah : first make sure u are getting value in Next Activity

Comment: you should implement onCheckedChanged()....this method will be called every time you check or uncheck....and write your condition inside this method...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK No I Am not getting value in next Activity..

Instead I Checked trying to display value in same activity..
that is also not working

Comment: but this is right answer for current problem you can try it by passing static value

Answer (score 0):

The lines are out of order:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Medicine.this, chk_med.class);
Medicine.this.startActivity(intent);
intent.putExtra("fvr", str);
```

Change to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Medicine.this, chk_med.class);
intent.putExtra("fvr", str);
Medicine.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This Thing Worked But Now It Shows Nothing In New Intent i.e chk_med